# Help in following proof of Intermediate Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Let $A=\{x:f(x)<0\}$ and let $s=\sup A.$ We shall show that $f(s) = 0$
>   (this is similar to the proof that $\sqrt2$ exists in Numbers and
>   Sets). If $f(s)<0,$ then setting $\epsilon=|f(s)|$ in the definition
>   of continuity, we can find $\delta>0$ such that $\forall y,|y − s|
> <\delta ⇒ f(y)<0.$ Then $s+\frac{\delta}2 \in A$, so $s$ is not an
>   upper bound. Contradiction.

It earlier defines a continuous function as follows:

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb R,a \in A,$ and $f:A \rightarrow \mathbb R.$ Then $f$ is continuous at $a$ if $(\forall \epsilon > 0) (\exists \delta > 0) (\forall y \in A) |y−a|<\delta ⇒ |f(y) − f(a)|<\epsilon.f$ is continuous if it is continuous at every $a \in A.$ That is $(\forall a \in A)(\forall \epsilon > 0)(\exists\delta >0)(\forall y \in A) |y − a|>\delta ⇒ |f(y) − f(a)| <\epsilon.$

I'm having a little difficulty following the proof, I just can't see the leap;
$"\forall y,|y − s| <\delta ⇒ f(y)<0.$ Then $s+\frac{\delta}2 \in A"$ and so I would appreciate it if anyone could explain this step.

Thank you

Comment: The point $s+\delta/2$ is distance less than $\delta$ away from s, is it not? i.e $|s+\delta/2-s|=\delta/2 < \delta$.

Comment: It may help to not write everything in formal logical symbols. That clouds both the text and your thinking. Drawing a picture in these instances will undoubtedly aid your intuition and rigor.

Answer (score 2):

$$\forall y, |y-s|< \delta \implies f(y)<0$$

means

$$\forall y, |y-s|< \delta \implies y \in A$$

Let $y=s+\frac{\delta}{2}$ and notice that $|y-s|=\frac{\delta}{2}< \delta$. Since the condition is satisfied, we have $y \in A$.

Answer (score 1):

From your wording of the question I gather that the essential difficulty is because of the use of symbols like $\forall, \exists$ and even the frequently used $\epsilon, \delta$. Without using any of these cryptic symbols it is very easy to prove an almost obvious property of continuous functions:

*If $f$ is a continuous at $a$ and $f(a)\neq 0$ then there is a neighborhood of $a$ in which $f$ has the same sign as that of $a$*.

Some textbook authors call it *the sign preserving property of continuous functions* and it is a type of *local property* (i.e. it deals with behavior of $f$ near a specific point).

The proof of the above property is simple. If $f$ is continuous at $a$ then by definition of continuity there is a neighborhood of $a$ where values of $f$ are near $f(a)$. If $f(a) \neq 0$ then we just need to ensure that values of $f$ are so near to $f(a)$ as to be of the same sign as that of $f(a)$.

In your question you have $f(s) < 0$. Then there is a neighborhood of $s$ where $f(x)$ is negative. The point $s + \delta/2$ is one such specific point of this neighborhood and it is greater than $s$. And by definition of set $A$ the point $s + \delta/2 \in A$ and we get a contradiction.

To rephrase your argument in a language which is rigorous and yet easy to understand you can proceed like this. You have $f(a) < 0, f(b) > 0$ and $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$. The set $A = \{x \mid x \in [a, b], f(x) < 0\}$ contains $a$ and some points near to and greater than $a$. At the same time $A$ does not contain point $b$ and all points near $b$ and less than $b$. So $s = \sup A$ exists and $a < s < b$. Now if $f(s) < 0$ then by sign preserving property of continuous functions there are points greater than and near to $s$ where $f$ is negative and these belong to $A$ and this contradicts that $s = \sup A$. If $f(s) > 0$ then $f$ is positive at all points near $s$ and less than $s$ and since $s = \sup A$ we must have points near to $s$ and less than $s$ such that $f$ is negative at those points. This is a contradiction. It follows that $f(s) = 0$.

---

On a side note you can observe the link between sign-preserving property of continuous functions (mentioned earlier) and the following restatement of intermediate value theorem:

**Intermediate Value Theorem**: *If $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ and does not vanish anywhere on $[a, b]$ then $f$ maintains same sign on whole interval $[a, b]$.*

So IVT is the generalization of the local property of sign preserving to a *global property*.